# how to match an inputs value to a .map function pulling data from an api

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a .map function displaying data that is being pulled from an api, I would like to add a field to the data and have it match to the relevant piece of data.

Fo example I am pulling ingredients from an api that contains quantities, I would like to add an input field that would allow me to add a multiplier that I could later use to multiply the ingredients.

Here is the .map function:

```
 <div className="mt-4 border-t border-b border-gray-200 divide-y divide-gray-200">
              {data.ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
                <div
                  key={ingredient.id}
                  className="relative flex items-start py-4"
                >
                  <div className="ml-4 flex items-center h-5">
                    <input
                      onChange={selectIngredient(ingredient.id)}
                      value={selectedIngredients.indexOf(ingredient.id === -1)}
                      type="checkbox"
                      className="focus:ring-purple-500 h-4 w-4 text-purple-600 border-gray-300 rounded"
                    />
                  </div>

                  <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
                    <label
                      className="font-medium text-gray-700 select-none"
                    >
                      {ingredient.name}
                    </label>
                  </div>
                  <div className="ml-3 text-sm">
                  // Here I am using useState to set a multiplier, but it sets the same vale for all data in the .map list.
                    <input
                      value={multiplier}
                      onChange={(e) => setMultiplier(e.target.value)}
                      type="number"
                      className="flex-1 focus:ring-purple-500 focus:border-purple-500 block w-full min-w-0 rounded-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

Here's what an ingredient object looks like:

```
ingredient: {
id: 1,
name: sugar,
quantity: 100,
quantityUnit: grams,
}
```

Is there a way I set an piece of state that is linked to the relevant mapped piece of data?

Comment: I'd suggest that you store all the data from the API into a state and add a `multiplier` property for each `ingredient` you get. Then use that dataset to render your fields.

Comment: Thanks @EmielZuurbier, how would I add the individual mutlipliers to the state?

Answer (score 1):

In your component, create a new state. Let's call this the `ingredients` state that has a `setIngredients` dispatcher. Set it by default as an empty array.

```
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = useState([]);
```

With a `useEffect` hook, loop over the received data with the `.map()` method and return a new object from each ingredient with a `multiply` property added. Update the `ingredients` state with this new array of objects.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (data.length) {
    setIngredients(
      data.map(ingredient => ({
        ...ingredient,
        multiply: 1
      })
    );
  }
}, [data]);
```

Now your `ingredients` state has all ingredients plus a `multiply` property for each ingredient.

Just to be sure, I've added this piece of (psuedo)code to demonstrate how the solution should work.

Every ingredient now has a `multiply` property, by default set to `1`. In your form you add a new input which handles the multiply value. The user is able to use the input to change the multiplication.

If needed, you could also add hidden input which tracks the total quanity of an ingredient (quantity * multiply). This might come in handy when you submit your form.

```
const handleMultiplyChange = (event, id) => {
  const value = Number(event.value)
  const updatedIngredients = ingredients.map(ingredient => ({
    ...ingredient,
    multiply: ingredient.id === id ? value : ingredient.multiply
  }));

  setIngredients(updatedIngredients);
};

return (ingredients.map(ingredient => (
  <>
    <input 
      type="checkbox"
      name="ingredient"
      value={ingredient.id}
    />
    <input 
      type="number" 
      name="multiply"
      min="1"
      value={ingredient.multiply}
      onChange={(event) => handleMultiplyChange(event, ingredient.id)}
    />
    <input 
      type="hidden"
      name="totalQuantity"
      value={(ingredient.multiply * ingredient.quantity)}
    />
  </>
));
```

Comment: Really appreciate the answer. My only is is the multiplier will be different for different ingredients. For example, an ingredient may be 100 grams of sugar and the recipe may require 500 grams of sugar, there for the multiplier fo sugar would be 5 and so on for different ingredients. How could I achieve this?

Comment: What are the multipliers based on? Does your data contain information anything about it or do you? Could you share what a single ingredient object looks like by editing it into your question?

Comment: Basically, I want to list all ingredients on a form that's going to be submitted to create a recipe. So the user on this for that will create the recipe will select the appropriate ingredients. The ingredients are stored in the database with default quantities (for example 100 grams of sugar), the user will select the relevant ingredient check box for the recipe and then add a multiplier that will multiply the default ingredient quantities to the desire amount for the recipe. I hope that makes sense on the role of the multiplier. Sure, I can update it.

Comment: I see what you mean. It means that this solution is still valid, as every ingredient has its own multiplier. You could even store the multiplication result of every ingredient inside a hidden input to send with the form while submitting.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. Will try this today and let you know how I go!